# C++ macros -- returning specified format

Tags: c++, macros

Is there a way to make macro using `#define`, which will take two arguments and "return" string in specified format with values of given arguments?

Something like this:

```
#define MACRO( x, y ) ( "OK ", x, " ", y, " \a\b" )     // i know this doesn't work

int main ()
{
  int a = 3,
      b = -1;

  std::cout << MACRO( a, b ) << std::endl;   // this should print following string: "OK 3 -1 \a\b"  

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This calls for a proper function. Why do you want a macro for this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want a macro, instead of a regular function? `( "OK " + std::to_string( x ) + " " + std::to_string( y ) + " \a\b")`

Comment: I currently have it via inline function... the reason I was asking if it could be done via macro is because it's part of a assignment for my class, which is aimed towards macros. But it could very well be just a trick question...

Comment: are you sure you want `"\a\b"`?

Comment: Yes, that's just specific message end in our environment where I submit my solution... same as "\0" for regular string.